# Moving monero from Poloniex or Bittrex to a paper wallet

Tags: exchange

Could I send Monero from an exchange (such as Poloniex) to the public address of my paper wallet?  Would that work?

I'm new to all this and not a techie person.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that would work. Just make sure you don't lose the seed for your paper wallet.

Answer (score 1):

If you were a techie, this [URL](https://github.com/skaht/XMR) should be most helpful plus the two other URLs it references at the bottom.  It is possible to have a brain wallet that maps to BIP 39 seed words that in turn map to Electrum seed words used to restore Monero wallets.